# AgGridReact - Grid does not update when isRowSelectable changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to pass `isRowSelectable` dynamically as a prop to an `AgGridReact`.  In the following toy example, You expect that clicking the "Switch criteria" button will change the set of items in the grid that have checkboxes. Instead, the grid is unchanged.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

```
interface Item { name: string, age: number, height: number}
const data: Item[] = [
    {name: "old and tall", age: 80, height: 80}, 
    {name: "old and short", age: 80, height: 20},
    {name: "young and tall", age: 10, height: 80}, 
    {name: "young and short", age: 10, height: 20}, 
]
const colDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
        headerName: "",
        checkboxSelection: true,
        headerCheckboxSelection: true,
        headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
        width: 60,
        sortable: false
    },
    { field: "name"},
    { field: "age"},
    { field: "height"}
]

const criteria1 = (node: RowNode) => node.data.age > 50
const criteria2 = (node: RowNode) => node.data.height > 50

export const DevPage: FunctionComponent = () => {

    const [isCriteria1, setIsCriteria1] = useState<boolean>(false)

    return ( <Fragment>
    
        <h2> {isCriteria1 ? "By Age" : "By Height"} </h2>
        <Button onClick = { () => setIsCriteria1(!isCriteria1) }> 
            Switch criteria
        </Button> 
        
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height:"800px"}}>
            <AgGridReact
                rowSelection="multiple"
                columnDefs = {colDefs}
                rowData={data}
                isRowSelectable = {isCriteria1 ? criteria1 : criteria2}
                suppressRowClickSelection={true}
            />
        </div>
        
    </Fragment> )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you can force all `RowNode`s to re-evaluate selectable property when `onClick` event fires.

```js
const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState<RowDataType[]>([]);
const criterial = React.useRef(true);
const isSelectable = (rowNode: RowNode) => {
  const result = rowNode.data.age > 25;
  const selectable = result === criterial.current;

  return selectable;
};
const toggleCriteria = () => {
  const updateSelectable = (rowNode: RowNode) => {
    rowNode.setRowSelectable(isSelectable(rowNode));
  };

  criterial.current = !criterial.current;
  gridApi.deselectAll();
  gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(updateSelectable);
};

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={toggleCriteria}>Toggle Criteria</button>
    <AgGridReact
      rowSelection="multiple"
      suppressRowClickSelection
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      isRowSelectable={isSelectable}
      rowData={rowData}
    />
  </>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64014770/aggridreact-grid-does-not-update-when-isrowselectable-changes/]

Comment: Thanks!  The only issue here is that this requires us to know when the prop changes.  In the toy example, a button switches the criteria.  In the real code it's just a prop that can change for a variety of reasons.  I suppose I can make this work with a useEffect on the prop.

Comment: Been 3 years and I wonder why they never fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the AG Grid issue. The AG Grid (tested with 28.2.1) is not refreshing state when an `isRowSelectable` function is changed.

You can force set row selectable by the `setRowSelectable` function

```
apiRef.current?.grid?.forEachNode(
  (rowNode: RowNode) => rowNode.setRowSelectable(isSelectable(rowNode))
)
```

Below a fork of the NearHuscarl approach with declared react dependencies on the `useCallback` and the `useState` functions.

```
const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState<Athlete[]>([]);
const [criterial, setCriteria] = React.useState(true);
const isSelectable = React.useCallback((rowNode: RowNode) => {
  const result = rowNode.data.age > 25;
  const selectable = result === criterial;
  return selectable;
}, [criterial]);
const toggleCriteria = React.useCallback(() => {
  setCriteria((c) => !c);
}, []);
React.useEffect(() => {
  apiRef.current?.grid?.deselectAll();
  apiRef.current?.grid?.forEachNode(
    (rowNode: RowNode) => rowNode.setRowSelectable(isSelectable(rowNode))
  )
}, [apiRef, isSelectable]);

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={toggleCriteria}>Toggle Criteria</button>
    <AgGridReact
      rowSelection="multiple"
      suppressRowClickSelection
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      isRowSelectable={isSelectable}
      rowData={rowData}
    />
  </>
);
```

### Live Demo

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/64014770-aggridreact-grid-does-not-update-when-isrowselectable-changes-forked-1wyl81?file=/src/Grid.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

we can use `gridParams.api.forEachNode()` to get each row node and then we can able to set checkbox select enable/disable option using `setRowSelectable()` method in the following way.

```
gridParams.api.forEachNode(node => {
    node.setRowSelectable(true) // this will enable checkbox select option 
    node.setRowSelectable(false) // this will disable checkbox select option
})
```