# Ag-grid isRowSelectable conditional not activating

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

We have an Ag-Grid table with row selection via the built in checkbox functionality.  The check boxes are conditionally displaying via the **isRowSelectable** options:

```
 isRowSelectable: function (rowNode) {
        return rowNode.data ? rowNode.data.published === false : true;
      }
```

The published column is being updated as part of a modal called from another column.  A **redrawRows** is being called when the modal is closed:

```
modal.result.then(() => {
            const row = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(params.rowIndex as number);
            //this.gridApi?.redrawRows([row] as any);
            this.gridApi?.redrawRows();
          });
```

The display values in the row are being updated when the modal is closed, however, the checkbox is not appearing when the published value is set to false.  If I hang a breakpoint in Dev Tools the isRowSelectable code does not appear to be hit.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

-John

Comment: Having the same issue; did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: A variant of this concept is working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856318/3622569

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see if it works?

```
let itemsToUpdate = [];

let data = rowNode.data;
// modify data fields
// Ex: data.field1 = "new value";

itemsToUpdate.push(data);

this.gridApi.applyTransaction({update: itemsToUpdate});
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-transactions/

Comment: Hi Sharath,  

Actually Shaune and I did try and leverage the applyTransaction({update}) function to resolve this and it did not work.

Cheers,

-John

Answer (score 0):

Use `refreshCells`

```
this.gridApi?.refreshCells({force:true});
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/view-refresh/#redraw-rows

Comment: Gave it a shot and unfortunately it the checkbox still does not reappear.  All of the row data gets updated as expected it just doesn't seem to hit that checkbox conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in AG Grid with React. A variant of this concept works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856318/3622569

```
  gridApi.forEachNode(
    (rowNode) => rowNode.setRowSelectable(isRowSelectable(rowNode))
  )
```

When your state changes, call code something like the above which runs the check again.

Comment: Hi, we actually transitioned away from using Ag-Grid when the project adopted Primeng.